# Increase displaying time of django messages

Tags: javascript, django

In my app, whenever a question is deleted, it shows a django message that question is deleted.
Related code is:

```
from django.contrib import messages

msg= _('Question is deleted')
messages.info(request, msg)
```

The message gets displayed as desired, however I want **Display message to last longer** say for minimum 10 sec. or till the user clicks on it.

In django docs saw expiration of messages but still could not figure out, and I have nothing like message storage which i can set to false.

Help appreciated :)

Comment: It's JavaScript territory probably, show your template code where the message is displayed.

Comment: But isn't the message just fed into your template and your template decides what to do with it, where to display it (and for how long if you have Javascript code to flash the message). The code above merely assigns the data and passes it into your template and then hands off the whole thing to your browser, where it renders it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The thing you want to do is javascript domain. Below code will display your messages for 10 sec or you can close it manually. In template you can do like this:

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <div class="message">
        {{ message }}
        <a href="#" class="del-msg">&times;</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

And in javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // messages timeout for 10 sec 
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.message').fadeOut('slow');
        }, 10000); // <-- time in milliseconds, 1000 =  1 sec

        // delete message
        $('.del-msg').live('click',function(){
            $('.del-msg').parent().attr('style', 'display:none;');
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The answer is correct, as when I set a limit as low as 10 or 100 it works but when I set a limit as 10000 i.e. to display for 10 sec it doesnt work. I believe thats cos 10 sec is more than the default time allowed by django messages. Kindly advise :)