# Set flashing time limit to django message.success?

Tags: python, django

Currently, when I do 
`messages.success(request, 'Article has been added to cart', extra_tags='add_to_cart')`
The message doesn't disappear unless I do close it manually. Is there any settings or parameters which I should set for auto-closing of the message box? How can I make like a flash message which would stay for defined time ?

Comment: that you should go with javascript

Comment: How? Can you help me with the same?

Answer (score 3):

This link should help you:
[Increase displaying time of django messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932653/increase-displaying-time-of-django-messages)
Answered by 
zubair89

The headline:
The thing you want to do is javascript domain. Below code will display your messages for 10 sec or you can close it manually.